# parallelize code in a gradle task

Tags: gradle

I have a task which essentially performs the following:

```
['subproj1', 'subproj2'].each { proj ->
    GradleRunner.create()
        .withProjectDir(file("./examples/${proj}/"))
        .withArguments('check')
        .build()
}
```

The check is a system test and requires connecting to 3rd party services, so I would like to parallelize this.

Can this be done in gradle?  If so, how?

I tried using java threading but the builds failed with errors which I can't remember what they were exactly, but they suggested that the gradle internal state had gotten corrupted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you tried to use the experimental parallel task execution? On the first glance it's quite simple. You just call `./gradlew --parallel` check (or if it turns out to work fine for you can also define this in your gradle.properties). This will start n threads (where n is the number cpu cores) which will execute your tasks. Each thread owns a certain project so the tasks of one project will never be executed in parallel.

You can override the number of tasks (or worker) by setting the property `--max-workers` at the command line or by setting `org.gradle.workers.max=n` at your gradle.properies.

If you are just interested in executing tests in parallel than you might try to set `Test.setMaxParallelForks(int)`. That will cause the to execute the tests of one project (if I understood this right) in parallel (with the number of tasks you defined).

Hope that helps. Maybe the gradle documentation gives you some more insights: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:parallel_execution

Comment: I had seen this parameter, but unfortunately, this seems to require projects to be setup as multi-project builds which mine aren't.  Maybe I need to refactor.

Comment: But if they are no multi-project you can run them completly independent of each other. If you invoke gradle then you do so to build one project (which might contain of different subprojects). I just suggested them to be multiproject builds because you named them subproject[1,2,3].

Comment: Maybe you could share some more insights on how your setup is. It is not allways a good idea to have one big project with a lot of subprojects. My rule of thumb would be: If a certain pice of software has it's one lifecycle (build, release, deploy) than it should be a stand-alone project.

Comment: The project is here: https://github.com/snowch/bluemix-spark-examples (see line 111 in the root build.gradle).  The top level build file main purpose is to test the independent projects in examples/*.  The example projects are intended to be as standalone as much as possible so that an example can be reused by just moving it somewhere else.

Comment: I just modified your build to a multiproject setup. Please have a look at this pull-request: https://github.com/snowch/bluemix-spark-examples/pull/6

Comment: Thanks @TobiSH I'll have a play around with it

Answer (score 0):

While multiproject build is the right way to go in the long term, my short term approach was to use GPars:

```
import groovyx.gpars.GParsPool

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.codehaus.gpars:gpars:1.1.0"
    }
}

task XXXX << {
    GParsPool.withPool(10) {
        ['subproj1', 'subproj2'].eachParallel { proj ->
            GradleRunner.create()
                .withProjectDir(file("./examples/${proj}/"))
                .withArguments('check')
                .build()
        }
    }
}
```